# Kotlin Banner ad overlapping Bottom activity Content

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

My Facebook Audience Network Banner ad overlaps the MainActivity Bottom Content and i don't know how to fix this issue, please see the screenshot to understand my issue Below :

[ScreenShot of the Overlapping Banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnVdR.png)

This is my MainActivity.kt Bannner ad code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    mActivity = this

    AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);

    adView = AdView(this, "IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#1903351453455935_1133844994875447", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50)

    // Find the Ad Container
    val adContainer = findViewById(R.id.banner_container) as LinearLayout

    // Add the ad view to your activity layout
    adContainer.addView(adView)

    // Request an ad
    adView!!.loadAd()
```

My MainActivity.Xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mai.xapkinstaller.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/loadingBg"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#34000000"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/progressLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#DBDBDB"
    android:paddingStart="48dp"
    android:paddingTop="24dp"
    android:paddingEnd="48dp"
    android:paddingBottom="24dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/progressMsg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progressMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/progressBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/dialog_to_confirm_that_the_user_wishes_to_exit_an_android_activity"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/banner_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

can you please help me with this !

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

To

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopof="@+id/banner_container"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: Kindly do some research on how to use ConstraintLayout

Comment: Thank you i will research it

Comment: Can you help me with something else please? i have created onBackPressed dialog but i don't know how to implement a Native ad on it !

Comment: Do some research, post a question having ur code and what did u try, people here will not write code for u until u show some efforts from urself as well